# Perl: Find maximum value of a hash and compute averages

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, bioinformatics

After a big break of ~6 months I am back in the world of Perl and Bioinformatics, interning under a different scientist. But the very first assignment is unlike any I had encountered last time, so while I have made some progress, I haven't been able to tackle the problem in its entirety. I am also trying to revise whatever I learnt last time as fast as possible, because I completely lost touch with programming these last 6 months.
The dataset looks like the following:

```
NR_046018   DDX11L1     ,   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1.44    2.72    3.84    4.92    5.6 6.64    7.08    9.12    9.56    8.28    7.16    6.08    5.4 4.36    3.92    1.88    0   0   0.76    1   1   1   1.2 2   2   2   1.72    2   2   2   1.8 1   1.88    2.4 3   3.36    5   6   6   6.72    6.12    5.6 5.44    5.56    5   4.04    5   4.28    4   4   3.08    2.08    1.68    1.96    1.44    3   3.68    4   4.16    5   4.32    4.8 6.16    6   6.28    6.92    7.84    7   7.32    7.2 5.96    5   4.52    4.08    3   3   4.04    4.12    4.44    4   3.52    3.4 4   4   2.64    1.88    1   1   1   0.64    1   1   1.24    2   2.92    3   3   2.96    2   2   2.56    2   1.08    2.12    3   3   3   3   2.6 3   4.64    3.88    3.72    4   4   4.96    4.6 4   2.36    2   1.28    1   1   0.04    0   0.24    1.08    2.68    3.84    4.12    5.72    6   6   5.76    4.92    3.32    3.12    2.88    2.08    2   2   2   2   2   1.44    2.92    3.04    4.28    5.8 7.8 9.48    10.52   13.04   12.08   11.6    11.72   11  9.2 7.52    7.12    7.08    7.08    8.32    7   6.6 7.6 8.04    8.36    6.72    7.88    7.72    8.4 9.24    8.88    8.96    9.88    10.08   9.24    9.28    10.16   11.04   10.52   10  8.56    8   7.8 7.72    6.44    4.32    4   4   3.72    3.68    3.68    3.28    5.56    7.36    9.48    10  10.52   11  12.16   11.96   9.44    8.64    7.52    7   6.48    6   5   5.12    6.28    6   5.52    6   6.68    6.08    7.52    8.16    7.72    8.52    8.56    9.2 9.16    8.92    7.44    6   5   3.48    2.92    2.16    2   2   1.2 1   1   1   1.24    1.64    1   1   1.96    2   2   2   1.76    1   1   1   0.52    1.76    3.64    5.12    6   6   6   6   5.52    4.24    2.36    0.88    0   0   0.68    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.32    0   0   1   1   1.44    2.44    3.68    5.4 6.88    7   6   6.52    6.76    6.56    5.32    3.6 2.92    3   3.72    3.96    3.8 3   3   3   2.2 2.4 2.28    1.52    1   1   1   1.72    2   1.6 1   1   1   1   1   0.28    0.92    2   2   2.72    3.64    4   4.84    5   4.08    3   3   2.68    2.36    2   1.16    1   1   2   4.92    4.6 4   4   4   4   4.32    4   1.08    1   1.52    2   2   2   1.68    1   1   1.32    1.48    1   1   1.52    2   2   2   1.68    1   1   1.88    1.48    1   1   1   1   1   1   0.12    0.4 1   1   1.2 3.88    4   5   5   4.6 4   4   3.8 2.08    2   1   1   1.44    2.4 3
NR_047520   LOC643837   ,   3   2.2 0.2 0   0   0.28    1   1   1   1   2.2 4.8 5   5.32    5   5   5   5   3.8 1.2 1   0.4 0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1.56    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.44    0.68    1   1.52    3   3.6 4.96    6.8 9   8.32    8.72    8.48    7   7.4 8.8 7.92    7.12    8.84    8.56    9.4 10.2    10  7.24    6.44    6.76    6.16    5.72    4.96    4.8 5.16    6   5.84    4.12    3   3   2.64    2.56    3.08    3   4.16    5   6.72    7   7.16    7.44    5.76    5   4.56    4   3.68    5   5.4 5.52    6   6   5.28    5   3.6 2   2.08    1.48    1   2   2   2   2   2   1.36    1   1   0   0   0.68    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.32    0   0   0   1.16    2   2   2   2   2.88    3   3   1.84    1   2   2   2.04    2.12    2   2   2   2   1   1.28    1.96    1.36    2.76    3   3   3   3   2.72    2   1.64    0.76    1   1.36    2   2   2   2   2   1.48    1   0.64    0   0.08    1   1   1.08    2   2   2   2   2.68    2   2   2.16    3.4 4   4   4.2 4.24    4   5.68    6.52    4.6 4   4   3.8 3.8 4   3.12    2.24    2.6 3   4   4   3.2 3   2.2 2   1.4 1.84    1.24    2   2   2   2   2   2   1.16    0.76    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.36    1   1.68    2   2   2.92    5.4 6.76    7.64    7   6.88    7   7.36    7.92    6.24    5.92    7.04    9.52    11.52   12.88   14.8    16.36   19.88   22.24   20  19.36   16.92   15.24   13.84   10.88   8.24    5.08    4.96    3.12    3   2.88    2   2.8 2.96    4   4.44    5   6   6   6   5.12    3.28    2   1.56    1   0.08    1.68    2   2   2.84    3   3   3.8 3.92    2.32    2   2.2 2.16    2   2   1.2 1   1   1   0.8 0   0   0   0.72    2.88    3   3   3   3   3   3   2.28    0.12    0   0.52    1   1   1   1   1.44    2   2   1.48    1   1   1   1.56    1.56    1   1   1   1   1   1   0.44    0.8 1.48    3   3   3   3   3   3.56    3.2 2.76    2   2   2   2   2.68    2.44    2   1.76    1   1.4 2   2   1.56    2   2   2   2   2.04    2   2   1.76    1   1   1   1   0.56    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.72    1.52    2   2   2   2   2   2   1.28    0.48
```

**1. What is needed**

1. For each row in the data file, find the maximum value from the range of numbers.
2. Once the maximum has been found for all the rows, find average maximum.

**2. Strategy I was thinking**

1. Separate the non numerical part from the non-numerical part into *"keys"* of a hash.
2. Put the numerical part into the *"values"* of a hash.
3. Assign the *"values"* into array `@values`
4. Use module `use List::Util qw(max)` to find maximum value from the array
5. Store these maximum values in another array and find average from this array.

**3. Code written so far**

```
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(max);

#Input filename
$file = 'test1.data';

#Open file
open I, '<', $file or die;

#Separate data into keys and values, based on ','
chop (%hash = map { split /\s*,\s*/,$_,2 } grep (!/^$/,<I>));
print "$_ => $hash{$_}\n" for keys %hash; #Code is working fine till here

#Create a values array
@values = values %hash;
foreach $value(@values){
 print "The values are : ", $value,"\n";
}
```

**4. The Problem**

Beyond this, I am not able to figure out how to add each `"individual"` array
element into a new array so that I may use the max function.

What I mean is that for example, the `first array element` in `@values` contains data like `0 0 1 1 3 4.4`. The `second array element` might have data like `3 2.2 0.28 1 1  4.8`. So I need to put `each` of these array elements into a new array, *each element* going into a *different array* so that I may be able to use the `max` function.

**5. Points to Note**

1. Most of the rows contain 400 numbers, some have a little less than that, but never more than 400.
2. There are a total of 23,558 rows.
3. File is a .txt file and all the numbers in each row are tab delimited.

I would be grateful to anyone who would be kind enough to point me in the right direction, or perhaps provide a better code to tackle the problem as mentioned in **1.**

Comment: you could also ask biostars: http://www.biostars.org/

Comment: @Pierre Many thanks for pointing me out to this site.

Comment: +1 for a very well-written question and showing work.

Comment: @Axeman Thank you sir! Coming from someone with a depth of experience as rich as yours makes the comment even more meaningful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you're making it overly complicated:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(max);

#Input filename
my $file = 'test1.data';

#Open file
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Unable to open $file: $!\n";

my ($total, $num);

while (<$fh>) {
    my @values = split;
    my $max = max(@values[3 .. $#values]);
    $total += $max;
    $num++;
}

my $average_max = $total / $num;
```

Just make one pass over your file, splitting the lines into an array and feeding everything from index `3` to `max`. Add `$max` to `$total` for each line, increment a counter (`$num`) and calculate average max from that.

You should also always use `use strict` and lexical filehandles.

Comment: Oh wow sir! Thank you so much! After looking at your solution, indeed I saw how overly complicated I was making things! :|  I have a lot to learn still it seems...

Comment: And yes sir, henceforth I will always use `use strict` and lexical filehandles.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fun solution. If you are using `List::Util`, you might as well use `sum` also.

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw/max sum/;

my %line_max = map {
    /([\w\s]*?)\s*,\s*(.*)/ or die "bad line";
    $1 => max split ' ', $2
} <DATA>;

print "$_: $line_max{$_}\n" foreach (keys %line_max);

my $avg_max = sum (values %line_max) / scalar (values %line_max);
print "average: $avg_max\n";

__DATA__
NR_046018   DDX11L1     ,   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1.44    2.72    3.84    4.92    5.6 6.64    7.08    9.12    9.56    8.28    7.16    6.08    5.4 4.36    3.92    1.88    0   0   0.76    1   1   1   1.2 2   2   2   1.72    2   2   2   1.8 1   1.88    2.4 3   3.36    5   6   6   6.72    6.12    5.6 5.44    5.56    5   4.04    5   4.28    4   4   3.08    2.08    1.68    1.96    1.44    3   3.68    4   4.16    5   4.32    4.8 6.16    6   6.28    6.92    7.84    7   7.32    7.2 5.96    5   4.52    4.08    3   3   4.04    4.12    4.44    4   3.52    3.4 4   4   2.64    1.88    1   1   1   0.64    1   1   1.24    2   2.92    3   3   2.96    2   2   2.56    2   1.08    2.12    3   3   3   3   2.6 3   4.64    3.88    3.72    4   4   4.96    4.6 4   2.36    2   1.28    1   1   0.04    0   0.24    1.08    2.68    3.84    4.12    5.72    6   6   5.76    4.92    3.32    3.12    2.88    2.08    2   2   2   2   2   1.44    2.92    3.04    4.28    5.8 7.8 9.48    10.52   13.04   12.08   11.6    11.72   11  9.2 7.52    7.12    7.08    7.08    8.32    7   6.6 7.6 8.04    8.36    6.72    7.88    7.72    8.4 9.24    8.88    8.96    9.88    10.08   9.24    9.28    10.16   11.04   10.52   10  8.56    8   7.8 7.72    6.44    4.32    4   4   3.72    3.68    3.68    3.28    5.56    7.36    9.48    10  10.52   11  12.16   11.96   9.44    8.64    7.52    7   6.48    6   5   5.12    6.28    6   5.52    6   6.68    6.08    7.52    8.16    7.72    8.52    8.56    9.2 9.16    8.92    7.44    6   5   3.48    2.92    2.16    2   2   1.2 1   1   1   1.24    1.64    1   1   1.96    2   2   2   1.76    1   1   1   0.52    1.76    3.64    5.12    6   6   6   6   5.52    4.24    2.36    0.88    0   0   0.68    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.32    0   0   1   1   1.44    2.44    3.68    5.4 6.88    7   6   6.52    6.76    6.56    5.32    3.6 2.92    3   3.72    3.96    3.8 3   3   3   2.2 2.4 2.28    1.52    1   1   1   1.72    2   1.6 1   1   1   1   1   0.28    0.92    2   2   2.72    3.64    4   4.84    5   4.08    3   3   2.68    2.36    2   1.16    1   1   2   4.92    4.6 4   4   4   4   4.32    4   1.08    1   1.52    2   2   2   1.68    1   1   1.32    1.48    1   1   1.52    2   2   2   1.68    1   1   1.88    1.48    1   1   1   1   1   1   0.12    0.4 1   1   1.2 3.88    4   5   5   4.6 4   4   3.8 2.08    2   1   1   1.44    2.4 3
NR_047520   LOC643837   ,   3   2.2 0.2 0   0   0.28    1   1   1   1   2.2 4.8 5   5.32    5   5   5   5   3.8 1.2 1   0.4 0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1.56    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.44    0.68    1   1.52    3   3.6 4.96    6.8 9   8.32    8.72    8.48    7   7.4 8.8 7.92    7.12    8.84    8.56    9.4 10.2    10  7.24    6.44    6.76    6.16    5.72    4.96    4.8 5.16    6   5.84    4.12    3   3   2.64    2.56    3.08    3   4.16    5   6.72    7   7.16    7.44    5.76    5   4.56    4   3.68    5   5.4 5.52    6   6   5.28    5   3.6 2   2.08    1.48    1   2   2   2   2   2   1.36    1   1   0   0   0.68    1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0.32    0   0   0   1.16    2   2   2   2   2.88    3   3   1.84    1   2   2   2.04    2.12    2   2   2   2   1   1.28    1.96    1.36    2.76    3   3   3   3   2.72    2   1.64    0.76    1   1.36    2   2   2   2   2   1.48    1   0.64    0   0.08    1   1   1.08    2   2   2   2   2.68    2   2   2.16    3.4 4   4   4.2 4.24    4   5.68    6.52    4.6 4   4   3.8 3.8 4   3.12    2.24    2.6 3   4   4   3.2 3   2.2 2   1.4 1.84    1.24    2   2   2   2   2   2   1.16    0.76    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.36    1   1.68    2   2   2.92    5.4 6.76    7.64    7   6.88    7   7.36    7.92    6.24    5.92    7.04    9.52    11.52   12.88   14.8    16.36   19.88   22.24   20  19.36   16.92   15.24   13.84   10.88   8.24    5.08    4.96    3.12    3   2.88    2   2.8 2.96    4   4.44    5   6   6   6   5.12    3.28    2   1.56    1   0.08    1.68    2   2   2.84    3   3   3.8 3.92    2.32    2   2.2 2.16    2   2   1.2 1   1   1   0.8 0   0   0   0.72    2.88    3   3   3   3   3   3   2.28    0.12    0   0.52    1   1   1   1   1.44    2   2   1.48    1   1   1   1.56    1.56    1   1   1   1   1   1   0.44    0.8 1.48    3   3   3   3   3   3.56    3.2 2.76    2   2   2   2   2.68    2.44    2   1.76    1   1.4 2   2   1.56    2   2   2   2   2.04    2   2   1.76    1   1   1   1   0.56    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.72    1.52    2   2   2   2   2   2   1.28    0.48
```

Note: the `map` syntax is cute, but if the file is large you should be using a while loop for efficiency.  The while loop avoids reading the whole file into memory:

```
while (<DATA>)
{
    if (/^([\w\s]*?)\s*,\s*(.*)/)
    {
        $line_max{$1} = max split ' ', $2;  
    }
    else
    {
        print "Line $. is bad.\n";  
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir! It represents another way to approach the problem at hand. I especially like this line `$1 => max split ' ', $2`. Could you please elaborate a little on it sir? It's a novel method for me and I would like to understand it a bit more.

Comment: @Neal, `$1`, `$2`, etc. are special variables that hold subpatterns that matched in the regular expression.  So `$1` contains the part of the line that you use for the hash key. `$2` contains the list of numbers.  Then I split the list of numbers by whitespace, select the maximum value out of that list, and use that as the hash value. The `=>` is merely a fancy version of a comma, often used for populating hashes: `my %hash = (key1 => 1, key2 => 123, key3 => 'foo')`

Comment: Ah! Brilliant approach sir! I guess, it is time I upgrade to reading something beyond the book I have been referring : `Beginning Perl for Bioinformatics`